# Can't Customize Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm very new to Chart.js and I'm working off the bar sample included when downloading Chart.js. I read through the documentation and the sample pages seem to do things a little differently. I tried following the documentation and online tutorials to no success, but working off the sample page is yielding better results.

However I can't seem to customize anything. I'm trying to start the scale value at 0 but it won't apply. This happens to all things I try to do (font color etc. etc. etc. etc.) The rest of the options here were included with the file and work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<head>
<title>Bar Chart</title>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<style>
canvas {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container" style="width: 75%;">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
    var barChartData = {
        labels: ["Week 1", "Week 2"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Round 1',
            backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            data: [12,15]
        }, {
            label: 'Round 2',
            backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            data: [20,17]
        }]

    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: barChartData,
            scaleOverride:true,
            scaleStartValue: 0, 

            options: {
                elements: {
                    rectangle: {
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        borderColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
                        borderSkipped: 'bottom'
                    }
                },
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    position: 'top',
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart'
                }
            }
        });

    };
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tick.beginAtZero`

```
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
    },
    ...
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7mse8p9e/